# Kendo UI splitter resize event

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using Jquery Kendo UI splitter,in which only right panel is collapsible.
I want to refresh left panel, when a resize and collapse is done for the right panel.
The logic for refresh is written in the resize event of the kendo splitter.
But the problem is that resize events gets called even when expand/collapse is performed.
Is there a way to prevent resize event in case of the expand of right panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is that the widget calls `expand` or `collpase` events **before** the `resize` event, so you can use your own flag to handle that, as the native `resize` event doesn't specifies which action is being performed.

Add a variable like below in your events:

```
let isCollapse = false;
function callMeOnlyOnCollapse() {
    console.log("Collapse!!!!");
}

function onResize(e) {
    if (isCollapse) {
        callMeOnlyOnCollapse();
    }
}

function onExpand(e) {
  isCollapse = false;
}

function onCollapse(e) {
  isCollapse = true;
}
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/obIGASez)